# A word that means "there and then"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

The word "there" indicates a point in space, and the word "then" indicates a point in time. Is there a word that indicates a point in spacetime, equal in meaning to "there and then"?

Comment: You might be able to bend *instance* or *occasion* to such meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have a word like that. I would rather use the phrase 'there and then', though I cannot think of a scenario where you would need that. Can you give me some more context here?

Comment: Something like, "Great! I'll meet you then and there." We'd like to use a single word instead the phrase. I don't think such a word exists.

Comment: It sounds as if you are wishing it to mean "I'll meet you at the appointed time and place"? Which could be shortened to I'll meet you at the appointment?  Failing that, you could make up a word.  I can't think of any which already exist.

Answer (score 0):

In physics, a point in space-time is known as an [event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_%28relativity%29).

(and a series of events is known as the [world line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line))

My guess for a term which isn't jargon would be something like "[spatiotemporal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spatiotemporal) position" or "spatiotemporal coordinates". While I can't access its definition, "[Temporospatial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temporospatial)" also exists and is probably a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

**Immediate** may be what you are looking for. Immediate carries the sense of both space and time.

**Forthwith** is another word (adverb) which means the same as *immediately*.

Comment: "Immediate" is a word that has two *separate* meanings of "now" (as in "immediate results"), and "here" (as in "immediate surroundings"). And I've never heard the word "forthwith" used in a spacial sense. Neither mean "then".

Comment: @MatthewPiziak: "Immediate aftermath" stands for *then*, don't you think?

Comment: @Shyam; no, it means 'immediately after then'.